# Can I join 2+ styles together into a superstyle?

Tags: css, class, styles

I was looking to join 2 styles together to make a super style for easy use and customisation of my page.

Is it possible to define something like this? (if so how)

```
.bold { font-weight: bold;}
.color1 {color: white;}

.boldColor {.bold; .color1;}

where .boldColor is effectively

.boldColor {font-weight:bold; color:white;}
```

I want this so that I can have styles thoughout the page and be able to easily change the colors in many places in 1 place. I'm currently using `<p class="bold color">` but some of my class defs are becoming long so I'd like to be able to use `<p class="boldColor">`

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you are asking for but you can get similar effects by using a comma to separate multiple css selectors that share the same properties.

```
.bold, .boldColor {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.color1, .boldColor {
    color: white;
}
```

This way `class="boldColor"` will have the same effect as `class="color1 bold"`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible using normal CSS. You would usually do this, as you already say, by combining class names: `bold color`

There are CSS "pre-compilers" that can do advanced things on CSS stylesheets, like working with variables. I don't know of any that does "class fusions" like you request but I'm sure they can be helpful in reducing code size. Check out [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [xCSS](http://xcss.antpaw.org/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

No, the CSS spec does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do this. How you are doing it currently is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [LessCss](http://lesscss.org/) ([.NET version](http://www.dotlesscss.com/))